# Please Explain the Output?

Tags: c

can anyone explain the strage output of the program I know that the value has nothing to do with the value stored in the array but with the pointer thing but how is the second value coming to be 5:

```
int main()
{
    int **h;
    int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};
    h=(int **)a;
    int i,j;
    printf("%d",*h);
    (*h)++;
    printf("\n%d",*h);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of providing a link please just post a code sample here.

Comment: int main()
{
int **h;
int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};
h=(int **)a;
int i,j;
printf("%d",*h);
(*h)++;
printf("\n%d",*h);
 
getch();
return 0;
}

Comment: I meant in the question... I'll do it.

Comment: @Ed S. In general I hate pastebins, but let's be honest here... ideone is awesome. It's much better than just posting code in the question - you can see the compiler warnings and the output. It's just a shame it's not integrated into SO like imgur is.

Comment: @Mark Byers yes sir I second u :)

Comment: How does `int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};` compile?

Comment: TBH, it shouldn't be tagged `c++`...

Comment: @Mark Byers: Ok, well fair enough; that is a good one.

Comment: @Mystical it does compile try it out

Comment: @AnkitSablok: The code sample you posted to ideone doesn't compile there. `undefined reference to getch` ... you should probably delete that line.

Comment: You're right, it does compile... I didn't know you could do that...

Comment: @Mark Byers sir u can modify the code to run in a g++ compiler but just let the logic remain there that array part basically and then u can explain me the output :-) I think I made myself clear now

Comment: @Griwes same u can read the above comment and try the same C/C++ doesnt matter

Comment: @AnkitSablok: But it's still C code, so C++ tag should not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the expression `*h` is a *pointer* type, pointer arithmetic comes into play.  Remember that pointer arithmetic takes the size of the base type into account; for any pointer of type `T *p`, the expression `p++` will advance the pointer `p` by `sizeof T` bytes.

Since `*h` is a pointer initialized to the value 1, the expression `(*h)++` is read as "add `sizeof (int *)` bytes to 1", which in your case is obviously 4.  Hence the output of 5.

Answer (score 4):

What's happening is that `*h` is of type `int*` which is a pointer.

When you increment it will actually increment by 4 rather than 1. Therefore the number you print out in the end is `1 + 4 = 5`.

Here's your code with more prints:

```
  int **h; 
  int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4}; 
  h=(int **)a; 

  cout << h[0] << endl;
  cout << h[1] << endl;
  cout << h[2] << endl;
  cout << h[3] << endl;

  int i,j; 
  printf("%d",*h); 
  (*h)++; 
  printf("\n%d",*h); 

  cout << endl;
  cout << h[0] << endl;
  cout << h[1] << endl;
  cout << h[2] << endl;
  cout << h[3] << endl;
```

The output is:

```
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
1
5
00000005
00000002
00000003
00000004
```

So you can see the first value, being incremented by 4. Because 4 is the size of the pointer when compiled for 32-bit.

Comment: what does this fragment do  int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};

Comment: also h[0] and so on like h[4] will all be (int *)'s so y is the code printing 1,2,3,4 when you try to print them

Comment: In this case, it's initializing the first 16 bytes of `a`, to `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. I honestly didn't know you could do this, so it might be undefined behavior. Someone want to add to this?

Comment: What you're doing here isn't exactly safe. But when you did `h=(int **)a;`, you set the pointer `h` to point the start of your array `{1,2,3,4}`. But `*h` is an array of pointers, so your values, `{1,2,3,4}` are being interpreted as pointers. So when you increment one of them, they will go up by 4.

Answer (score 0):

By the statement `h=(int **)a;` you have only allocated the memory address(the first) of the array `a` to `h`. You have also defined h as a **pointer to a pointer** which can also point to a two-dimensional array as you have done. Also, to be seen, you have **not made `h` a two-dimensional array**(using `malloc` recursively). By `printf("%d",*h);`, you are trying to access the value at the address stored in `h`.

Arrays store values in memory in two ways, either **column-wise or row-wise**. In either ways the memory locations are sequential, in your case also. So, `h` stores the memory address of the first element of the array `a`. Therefore, when you use `*h` it retrieves the value at the address stored in `h`, i.e., the first value in array `a`. And when you increment `*h` by `(*h)++`, it increments because `*h` is still a pointer, and as you know incrementing a pointer doesn't mean incrementing by `1`, it **actually increments by `4`**.

Hence, you are getting the above-mentioned output of yours.

Further discussions are welcomed from you **Ankit**.

-**Sandip**